# How do I override the default layout

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I am new to PHP and today I was able to display my first list of items using CakePHP yay! but, whatever I display always shows with the default format. How can I override my view to show the page how I had it in html? Where do I put the css, javascript and images? Before this my HTML had this in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylestopmenu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylessidemenu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.rating.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/specialtablemenu.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admintable.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have no idea how to style it so that it displays as before. Right now it shows like this

[image]

I wouldn't like to totally get rid of this as it tells me errors but, how can i do it so that I can style the page, maybe somewhere else?, please forgive me, I am new to PHP and its been hard for me to understand the tutorials. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP lets you override pretty much anything, you just need to understand its structure. The best thing to do is to copy the default.ctp file from your cake folder in `APP_DIR\cake\libs\view\layouts\default.ctp`.

Once you've copied this, place it in `APP_DIR\app\views\layouts\` and cake will start using that file. To customize it, simply open up that file and change it in your editor.

Comment: One small question, where should i place my images, css and javascript?

Comment: Usually APP_DIR/app/webroot/img/ for images and APP_DIR/app/webroot/js/ for scripts. But it doesn't matter as long as you put it in webroot since you can simply edit your layout to point anywhere. Just make sure to use the helpers or the URL helper to generate the paths.

Comment: If you place appropriate assets in the appropriate directory (`css`, `js`, `img`), you can take advantage more easily of the HTML Helpers, without messing with `$this->webroot`. EG: `<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot . '/img/foo.jpg'; ?> " />` becomes `<?php echo $this->Html->image('foo.jpg'); ?>`.

Comment: @Ross you don't need webroot. You can also just as easily do `$this->image('/images/foo.jpg');`. Just need to use absolute path.

Comment: @JohnP good point - but unless I'm mistaken, this could make an app potentially less portable if a user has customised the location of the webroot (e.g out of `root`); unless the `.htaccess` re-writes were updated accordingly as well.

Comment: @Ross won't make a difference because the paths you put are absolute paths _from_ the webroot of your application. So you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your custom layout in your controller to override default layout:

```
//in controller say in beforeFilter
function beforeFilter() {
 parent::beforeFilter();
 $this->layout = "your_layout_name";
}
```

Hope it helps